# How to use SFTP BatchMode inside EXPECT[Shell Script]

Tags: linux, shell, shell-scripting, expect

I have set of series SFTP commands which needs to run inside expect.

But when i run the below script due to some reasons am not getting any output. Please correct me if am wrong any where inside the script.

```
expect << EOF
spawn sftp -oPort=23 -oBatchMode=no -b cmds.txt xxx@1x.2.2x.8x
sleep 3
expect "xxx@1x.2.2x.8x's password:"
send "hello123\r"
EOF
```

But when i run below command in CLI interface it works super good:

```
# spawn sftp -oPort=23 -oBatchMode=no -b cmds.txt xxx@1x.2.2x.8x
```

For Security Reasons, I cant use SCP, SSHPASS, KeyChain Etc.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have told expect to send the password, it has nothing to do so it stops and kills the sftp. Add a wait for end-of-file from the spawned command:

```
expect eof
```

You can get more debug from expect by starting it with `expect -d`.

Comment: Awesome, I have been breaking my head for last 4 days.